# How to measure phpDoc coverage?

Tags: php, annotations, documentation, phpdoc

Is there any way I can measure if all my PHP classes and methods have proper PHPdoc comments?

I.e. if there are enough `@param` definitions, a `@return` statement, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/docs) checks for PHPDoc comments.

Comment: hi , i'm very interested about this, can u give details about it ?

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel The link still works. Click on the "[End-user Documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php)" link to read more.

Comment: thanks , i have no idea where to look since the link you provided is the root directory :)